# A Half Partition of Borel Sets will Give Half the Borel Measure

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, solution-verification, alternative-proof, borel-measures

Here is the problem:

Let $n \in \mathbf{N}$ and define $A_n := \bigcup_{k \in \mathbf{Z}} [\frac{2k}{2^n}, \frac{2k + 1}{2^n})$. If $E \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbf{R})$, show the limit
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \lambda(A_n \cap E) = \frac{\lambda(E)}{2}.
$$
I have successfully proven that for all $E \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbf{R})$ that is **bounded**. The problem that I am facing right now is to extend from the bounded case to unbounded case.

My idea was to split $E = \bigcup_{m = 1} ^\infty E \cap B(0, m) =: \bigcup_{m = 1} ^\infty E_m$, with $B(0, m)$ being the ball with radius $m$. This would give us by the continuity of measure that
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \lambda(A_n \cap E) = \lim_{n \to \infty} \lim_{m \to \infty} \lambda(A_n \cap E_m).
$$
Now ideally we would really like to switch the order of limit here. However, I can not justify if we could do so or not. Is there another way to approach the unbounded case? Any idea would be appreciated.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/283737/weak-convergence-of-a-sequence-of-characteristic-functions

Comment: The question referred to by Anne deals with the bounded case (specifically $[0,1]$).

Comment: @AnneBauval Hmm Interesting. Although this doesn't answer my question, it's nice to see another approach doing the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I will assume that OP has already established the claim for bounded Borel subsets. Then we will prove the claim for arbitrary Borel $E \subseteq \mathbb{R}$.

---

**1.** First, assume $\lambda(E) < \infty$. We fix a partition $(E_j)_{j\in J}$ of $E$ into bounded Borel sets. (For example, we can set $E_j = E \cap [j, j+1)$ and $J = \mathbb{Z}$.) Note that $ \sum_{j\in J} \lambda(E_j) = \lambda(E) < \infty$. Then

$$ 0 \leq \lambda(E_j \cap A_n) \leq \lambda(E_j) \qquad\text{and}\qquad \lim_{n\to\infty} \lambda(E_j \cap A_n) = \frac{1}{2}\lambda(E_j), $$

and so, the dominated convergence theorem is applicable. Hence,

\begin{align*}
\lim_{n\to\infty} \lambda(E \cap A_n)
&= \lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{j\in J} \lambda(E_j \cap A_n) \\
&= \sum_{j\in J} \lim_{n\to\infty} \lambda(E_j \cap A_n)
= \sum_{j\in J} \frac{1}{2} \lambda(E_j)
= \frac{1}{2} \lambda(E).
\end{align*}

---

**2.** Now suppose $\lambda(E) = \infty$. Then for any $r > 0$,

$$ \liminf_{n\to\infty} \lambda(E \cap A_n)
\geq \liminf_{n\to\infty} \lambda(E \cap [-r, r] \cap A_n)
= \frac{1}{2}\lambda(E \cap [-r, r]). $$

Since $r$ is arbitrary, letting $r \to \infty$ shows that

$$ \liminf_{n\to\infty} \lambda(E \cap A_n) \geq \infty, $$

which immediately implies the desired claim for unbounded Borel sets.

Comment: Why is $\sum_{j \in J} \lambda(E_j) = \lambda(E)$, if $E_j$ is a partition of $\mathbf{R}$?

Comment: Ah, it seems like I am still not fully sober yet. Sorry for the confusion, it is fixed now (or so I believe) :)

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I really like the use of LDCT in counting measures.

Answer (score 2):

Consider $E \subset \mathbb R$ with $\lambda(E) < \infty$.  Given $\epsilon$, there is $R$ such that $\lambda(E \backslash [-R,R]) < \epsilon$.  Then
$$ \liminf_{n \to \infty} \lambda(A_n \cap E) \ge \lim_{n \to \infty} \lambda(A_n \cap E \cap [-R,R]) = \frac{1}{2} \lambda(E \cap [-R,R]) > \frac{1}{2} (\lambda(E) - \epsilon)$$
while
$$ \limsup_{n \to \infty} \lambda(A_n \cap E) \le \lim_{n \to \infty} \lambda(A_n \cap E \cap [-R,R]) + \lambda(E \backslash [-R,R]) = \frac{1}{2} \lambda(E \cap [-R,R]) + \lambda(E \backslash [-R,R]) \le \frac{1}{2} \lambda(E) + \epsilon/2$$

Take $\epsilon \to 0$ and we get $\lim_{n \to \infty} \lambda(A_n \cap E) = \frac{1}{2} \lambda(E)$.

On the other hand, if $\lambda(E) = \infty$, then for any $M$ there is $R$ so that $\lambda(E \cap [-R,R]) > M$.  We get
$$\liminf_{n \to \infty} \lambda(A_n \cap E) \ge \lim_{n \to \infty} \lambda(A_n \cap E \cap [-R,R]) = \frac{1}{2} \lambda(E \cap [-R,R]) > M/2$$
Takng $M \to \infty$, we see that $\lim_{n \to \infty} \lambda(A_n \cap E) = \infty$.

Comment: While a the other LDCT way is bit slicker, this is also a great answer. I should learn that there is this nice way to extend from bounded sets to finite measures using the continuity of measures. One question: when showing the limsup inequality, there should have been an $\epsilon > 0$ in the end, right?

Comment: Actually $\epsilon/2$ (edited).